# How to take backup of an entire database which is under a Clickhouse cluster

Tags: clickhouse-backup

I've successfully set up a two-node ClickHouse cluster in a test environment and am currently exploring the process of backing up an entire database hosted on the cluster. The database uses 'ReplicatedMergeTree' engine for its tables. I have specified a particular folder within the root directory to store the backup files. However, I am encountering difficulties in the backup process. Although I have successfully backed up and restored databases in non-cluster setups before, the procedure appears to be more intricate for databases within a cluster. Any help in this will be highly appreciated.

I am using the below command to take backup

`BACKUP DATABASE mytestdb ON CLUSTER 'defaulta' TO Disk('backups', 'testdb_backup');`